# storing array state objects in asyncStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I want to store an array state using async storage. but everytime i reload the app, it comes up blank. below is a sample code, and I have shown only the functions for better clarity.

```
    componentDidMount() {
      this.getDataSync();
    }


  getDataSync = async () => {
    try {
      const list = await AsyncStorage.getItem(LIST_STORAGE_KEY);

      const parsedList = JSON.parse(list);
      const obj = Object.keys(parsedList);

      this.setState({ isDataReady: true, list: obj || [] });
    } catch (e) {
      Alert.alert('Failed to load list.');
    }
  }

  handleAdd() {
    const { firstname, lastname, email, phone} = this.state;
    const ID = uuid();
    const newItemObject = {
        key: ID,
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        image: null,
    };

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      list: [...prevState.list, newItemObject]
    }));

    this.saveItems(this.state.list);

  }

  saveItems = list => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(LIST_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(list));
  };
```

Comment: Try to log a list and obj and tell me what u got

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not saving your list but getting keys from the list. `const obj = Object.keys(parsedList);` you are saving array indexes to state.

```
getDataSync = async () => {
  try {
    const list = await AsyncStorage.getItem(LIST_STORAGE_KEY);

    const parsedList = JSON.parse(list);

  this.setState({ 
     isDataReady: true, 
     list: Array.isArray(parsedList) && parsedList.length && parsedList || [] 
  });

 } catch (e) {
    Alert.alert('Failed to load list.');
  }
}
```

Also pass `saveItems` as a callback to save the correct data.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  list: [...prevState.list, newItemObject]
}), () => this.saveItems(this.state.list));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`.setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) method is [may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), so the result of setting the state, cannot be used immediately after setting it. If you want to use the results of setting the state, you should use the callback (2nd param), which is called after the state is actually set:

```
this.setState(
  prevState => ({
    list: [...prevState.list, newItemObject]
  }),
  () => this.saveItems(this.state.list)
);
```

Comment: its not working, tried it before and tried it now, still returning an empty array.

Comment: getting Array [ "0"]